# Pass AJAX return to Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am running a python REST server, using Flask, to create a website. On the website, I have a number of buttons that call various 3rd party APIs, using AJAX, and get the information back.

The APIs work, and I can get the information back (confirmed that it is accurate using console.log). However, I can't figure out how, or where to pass the information from the AJAX to the server, so that I can process it.

My HTML/JS code is:

```
<script>

    function Enquiry() {
        var selection = document.getElementById("Selection").value

        // Get values for API        
        var n = selection.indexOf(" ");
        var symbol = selection.substring(0,n)
        var API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=" + symbol + "&apikey=XXX"

        // AJAX to API
        $.ajax({
            url: API_URL,
            method: "GET",
            data: "",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result)
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,error){
                console.log("error: "+status+" msg:"+error);
            }
        });
    } 
    </script>
```

And my Flask script is:

```py
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template(Stocks.html)

@app.route("/Stocks")
def getAll():
    results = stocksDAO.getAll()
    return jsonify(results)

@app.route("/Stocks/<int:id>")
def getById(id):
    sel_stock = stocksDAO.findById(id)
    return jsonify(sel_stock)

@app.route("/Stocks", methods=["POST"])
def create():

    if not request.json:
        abort(400)

    stock = {
        "Stock": request.json["Stock"],
        "Name": request.json["Name"],
        "Price": request.json["Price"],
    }
    values = (stock["Stock"], stock["Name"], stock["Price"])
    newId = stocksDAO.create(values)
    stock["ID"] = newId

    return jsonify(stock)
```

Comment: You should make an ajax call to your own server. The best way would probably to make the 3rd party call inside of your server code instead of in the front-end

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the user to input values at the front end, before the call is made.

Comment: You could still send that input value to your server and then make the 3rd party call from there

Comment: Either way, how do I pass the user inputs into Python?

Comment: @Clauric To send user data as an input in the js, inside of the `"data"` add `{"test":"test input"}` then inside of the your flask script `import request from Flask` and inside the function you can get the body of the post request by doing `request.json()`

Comment: you should send that request either via get or post parameters, depending on the type of request you make. lookup how to send parameters in jQuery and how to retrieve them in flask